# Assign Thymeleaf dialect expression return value to Thymeleaf variable in th:with

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm desperately trying to assign a Thymeleaf dialect expression return value to Thymeleaf variable in the `th:with` attribute.

I want to achieve something like:

```html
<th:block th:with="foo=${#lists.contains(modelList, modelVariable)}" />
```

Note: I'm completely sure that my `#lists.contains` expression works since I've printed the return value in an `h1` tag and returns `true` as text:

```html
<h1 th:text="${#lists.contains(modelList, modelVariable)}"></h1>
```

So far I've tried the following syntaxes, all of them giving me a parsing error in some way or another...

Without the external `${}`:

```html
<th:block th:with="foo=#lists.contains(modelList, modelVariable)" />
```

With preprocessing:

```html
<th:block th:with="foo=${__#lists.contains(modelList, modelVariable)__}" />
```

With preprocessing and wrapping it in `${}`:

```html
<th:block th:with="foo=${__${#lists.contains(modelList, modelVariable)}__}" />
```

Why any of these expressions work?

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug/impossibility of Thymeleaf `th:with` expression?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the `th:with` expression itself.  However, variables created using `th:with` only apply to children tags.  Your `th:block` is immediately closed, therefore `foo` is immediately out of scope and nothing can access it.  For example, this would work:

```
<th:block th:with="foo=${#lists.contains(modelList, modelVariable)}">
    <div th:text="${foo}" />
</th:block>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<th:block th:with="foo=${#lists.contains(modelList, modelVariable)}" />
<div th:text="${foo}" />
```

There is no way to define a global variable like that (except putting in on the `<html />` tag I suppose).

Comment: No way...I knew that :( I don't know why I closed the tag. I'll try it later and tell you if you were right. I'm sure that's the problem. Thank you!

Comment: You were completely right! Now it's working fine, thanks again! :)